# opencv user drawing visible rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code where a user can select a rectangle of an image to crop it, however the rectangle isn't visible while they are drawing it making it difficult. does anyone have an idea how I could modify code like this to make it visible while I draw?

this is my cut and crop method-

```
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):

global refPt, cropping

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    refPt = [(x, y)]
    cropping = True

elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    refPt.append((x, y))
    cropping = False

    cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", closeres)
```

as you can see from this code it only shows the rectangle after the mouse button lets up, is there some way for it to be drawn as they are drawing it at event left button down? like maybe the first point of the triangle is where they click and the second is wherever the mouse is?

EDIT---

i followed that tutorial and changed method to this -

```
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):

global refPt, drawing, cropping

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    drawing = True
    refPt = [(x, y)]
    cropping = True

elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing == True:
        cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], (x,y),(0,255,0),2)


elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing = False
    refPt.append((x, y))
    cropping = False

    cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", closeres)
```

and it draws continuous rectangles each mouse move instead of just one rectangle changing size, does anyone know how to fix?

[image]

Comment: You need to keep a copy of the original image, and draw a new rectangle each time when the mouse is moving (`event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)`. Take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html. I think it does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled this topic and didn't find a working example of what you want.

Also the answer by cxyzs7 in the comment is correct, but the linked example does not do what you want.

Since `cv2.rectangle` overwrites directly your input image, you have to supply a new image every `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP` event. This works only if you define both images as `global` in your callback function, otherwise the image variable will be local to your function (see [namespaces in python](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/)).

I have therefore modified the example from the [OpenCV mouse handling demo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html) to do what you want:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False  # true if mouse is pressed
ix, iy = -1, -1

# mouse callback function
def draw_rectangle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, img, original_img

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            img = original_img.copy()
            cv2.rectangle(img, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 0)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        img = original_img.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), -1)
        original_img = img.copy()


original_img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
img = original_img.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", draw_rectangle)

while 1:
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```